# Need to transfer all charts from Excel in PPT

Tags: vba

I have a script which transfer all my charts to PPT perfectly but the issue is all chart paste in different slides. I have small charts that mean in a single slide can be store 4 charts. Is there any kind of script which arrange the charts as well in PPT slide and paste at least 4 charts in single slide of PPT.
Currently I'm using the below code

```
Sub Chart_TRF()
Dim PApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim slide_index As Integer

Dim Chrt As ChartObject

Set PApp = New PowerPoint.Application

PApp.Visible = True

Set PPres = PApp.Presentations.Add
slide_index = 1
For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
Chrt.Copy
Set PSlide = PPres.Slides.Add(slide_index, ppLayoutBlank)
PSlide.Shapes.Paste
slide_index = slide_index + 1
Next Chrt

MsgBox ("PPT is created for all Charts")

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have any query on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have amended your code so that each slide will contain 4 charts.  You can change the starting left and top positions, along with the gap between charts, as desired.

```
Sub Chart_TRF()

    Const START_LEFT_POS As Long = 20 'change the starting left position as desired
    Const START_TOP_POS As Long = 20 'change the starting top position as desired
    Const GAP As Long = 30 'change the gap between charts as desired

    Dim PApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim slide_index As Integer
    Dim chart_index As Integer
    Dim left_pos As Integer
    Dim top_pos As Integer
    
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    
    Set PApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    
    PApp.Visible = True
    
    Set PPres = PApp.Presentations.Add
    
    slide_index = 0
    chart_index = 0
    left_pos = START_LEFT_POS
    top_pos = START_TOP_POS
    For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        chart_index = chart_index + 1
        If chart_index Mod 4 = 1 Then
            slide_index = slide_index + 1
            Set PSlide = PPres.Slides.Add(slide_index, ppLayoutBlank)
            top_pos = START_TOP_POS
        End If
        Chrt.Copy
        Set PShape = PSlide.Shapes.Paste(1)
        If chart_index Mod 2 = 1 Then
            With PShape
                .Left = left_pos
                .Top = top_pos
                left_pos = left_pos + .Width + GAP
            End With
        Else
            With PShape
                .Left = left_pos
                .Top = top_pos
                left_pos = START_LEFT_POS
                top_pos = top_pos + .Height + GAP
            End With
        End If
    Next Chrt
    
    MsgBox ("PPT is created for all Charts")

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here's the code that will copy the charts from all worksheets in the active workbook.

```
Sub Chart_TRF()

    Const START_LEFT_POS As Long = 20 'change the starting left position as desired
    Const START_TOP_POS As Long = 20 'change the starting top position as desired
    Const GAP As Long = 30 'change the gap between charts as desired

    Dim PApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim slide_index As Integer
    Dim chart_index As Integer
    Dim left_pos As Integer
    Dim top_pos As Integer
    
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set PApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    
    PApp.Visible = True
    
    Set PPres = PApp.Presentations.Add
    
    slide_index = 0
    chart_index = 0
    left_pos = START_LEFT_POS
    top_pos = START_TOP_POS
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Chrt In ws.ChartObjects
            chart_index = chart_index + 1
            If chart_index Mod 4 = 1 Then
                slide_index = slide_index + 1
                Set PSlide = PPres.Slides.Add(slide_index, ppLayoutBlank)
                top_pos = START_TOP_POS
            End If
            Chrt.Copy
            Set PShape = PSlide.Shapes.Paste(1)
            If chart_index Mod 2 = 1 Then
                With PShape
                    .Left = left_pos
                    .Top = top_pos
                    left_pos = left_pos + .Width + GAP
                End With
            Else
                With PShape
                    .Left = left_pos
                    .Top = top_pos
                    left_pos = START_LEFT_POS
                    top_pos = top_pos + .Height + GAP
                End With
            End If
        Next Chrt
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox ("PPT is created for all Charts")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Domenic. This code is working absolutely fine.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the feedback, cheers!

Comment: Hi Domenic,

Using this code i can extact PPT from the active sheet is there any option which extract all the ppt from all sheets in workbooks.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the code to copy charts from all worksheets in the active workbook.